# Responsive layout - make picture go above text when on small screen

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I have this responsive layout on my site. When the screen is less than 767px wide the image is tucked under the text. Is there a way to make the image (and caption i.e. `.rightColumn`) go above the `.leftColumn` instead?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { margin: 0; }

.columnsContainer { position: relative; margin: 1.5em 0; padding:1.5em ; border: 1px solid  #fff;}

.leftColumn { margin-bottom: .5em; }

.rightColumn .wp-caption{border-width: 0px;}

.rightColumn {min-height:100%;}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (min-width: 767px ) {
  .leftColumn { margin-right: 51%; }

    .rightColumn { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 48.5%; }   
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title>Responsive Two Column Layout (Left Column Fluid)</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>
  
  <body>
 <div class="columnsContainer">
<div class="leftColumn">
<h2 style="width: 100%; font-family: Aller;"></h2>
<h2 style="width: 100%; font-family: Aller;">BEST OF SCOTLAND
FISHING BREAK</h2>
<ul class="checkmark">
    <li>2 Days each of guided salmon, pike &amp; trout/grayling fishing</li>
    <li>7 Night bed &amp; breakfast</li>
    <li>Full equipment &amp; transfers provided</li>
    <li>Peak season 1st April - 15th November</li>
    <li>Glasgow or Edinburgh airport transfers Included</li>
    <li><span style="font-family: Aller;">1 hour from Edinburgh, Glasgow &amp; Perth</span></li>
</ul>
<a href="http://scotiafishing.com/wp-content/uploads/Best-Of-Scotland-Package.pdf" rel="">View Trip Dossier</a>

</div>
<div class="rightColumn">
<p style="text-align: right;">

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-4684" src="http://scotiafishing.com/wp-content/uploads/bofs.jpg" alt="best-of-scotland-break" width="415" height="277" /> 
  <br>Experience the best of Scotland's fishing with this six day break!

</p>

</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to add the `rightColumn` div before the `leftColumn`  div. It should not mess the structure up and will show the image first

```
<div class="rightColumn">
<p style="text-align: right;">

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-4684" src="http://scotiafishing.com/wp-content/uploads/bofs.jpg" alt="best-of-scotland-break" width="415" height="277" /> 
  <br>Experience the best of Scotland's fishing with this six day break!

</p>

</div>
<div class="leftColumn">
<h2 style="width: 100%; font-family: Aller;"></h2>
<h2 style="width: 100%; font-family: Aller;">BEST OF SCOTLAND
FISHING BREAK</h2>
<ul class="checkmark">
    <li>2 Days each of guided salmon, pike &amp; trout/grayling fishing</li>
    <li>7 Night bed &amp; breakfast</li>
    <li>Full equipment &amp; transfers provided</li>
    <li>Peak season 1st April - 15th November</li>
    <li>Glasgow or Edinburgh airport transfers Included</li>
    <li><span style="font-family: Aller;">1 hour from Edinburgh, Glasgow &amp; Perth</span></li>
</ul>
<a href="http://scotiafishing.com/wp-content/uploads/Best-Of-Scotland-Package.pdf" rel="">View Trip Dossier</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap and use `flex-reverse-column` this should work

````
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assests/style.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>HELLO BOOTSTRAP</h1>

  <div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">

    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In at laoreet tortor,
        vitae sodales magna. Curabitur vel feugiat magna, vitae vehicula nibh. Proin
        eget lobortis mi. Sed dapibus urna quis risus fringilla ultrices. Praesent lacinia
        fermentum velit, vitae ultricies nibh porttitor quis. Aenean nisi mi, elementum id
        quam eu, tristique porta nunc. Vestibulum ac faucibus lorem. Donec sit amet metus
        venenatis nisi tincidunt ultrices. In semper nibh nunc, at posuere purus rhoncus
        ac. Mauris pulvinar sed mauris quis efficitur. Proin sollicitudin euismod purus,
        a gravida neque cursus sed. Etiam faucibus aliquet metus, ut accumsan augue
        suscipit nec. Donec laoreet nisi nibh, ac egestas nisl hendrerit sit amet.
        Morbi scelerisque, velit quis suscipit viverra, sem velit varius nulla, vitae
        tincidunt felis elit sit ametdolor. Nulla mi tellus, imperdiet nec nisi non, 
        suscipit suscipit lacus. Nunc porttitor nibh at purus dignissim mollis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus sodales tempor turpis, a vehicula sem. Donec et leo in lorem venenatis
        interdum at non risus. Maecenas aliquam, turpis at posuere tristique, nunc
        nibh maximus nisl, a tristique lacus turpis a ligula. Proin gravida
        id odio eget facilisis. Phasellus varius quis arcu in lobortis. Vivamus eu condimentum velit.
        Praesent massa purus, iaculis eget consectetur sed, dictum in turpis. 
        Mauris quis tempus massa. Sed quam justo, viverra id
        ligula sit amet, aliquet vehicula tortor.
      </p>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" alt="unsplash">
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JQuery-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>```
````